# FTP from terminal if username contains @?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, ftp

How do you connect to an FTP server from the command line if your username is your email address? Usually I login in like this:

```
ftp username@ftp.server.com
```

But if my username is an email address, it doesn't work:

```
ftp myname@mysite.com@ftp.server.com
```

I've tried using an escape character \@, and putting the username in quotes. Neither work. I looked in the man pages and searched Google to no avail.

Comment: Could you maybe use `curl -u user:password ...ftp://sever/dir/dir/file` instead? Or same with `lftp` client?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to `man ftp` and you shoud use `$HOME/.netrc` file containing the username. See:

> user User [Password] [Account]    Identifies the local user (User)
>   to the remote FTP server. If the Password or Account parameter is not specified and the remote server requires it, the ftp command prompts for the password or account locally. If the Account parameter is required, the ftp command sends it to the remote server after the remote login process completes.